# Django blog application - views, urls, models, forms

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I want to learn how to create websites and I have started learning Django web framework. I think Django is very good alternative for PHP and it isn't too complex as JEE. I'm very satisfied learning Django framework. So, within the framework of science I made a blog in Django. I would receive an opinion about quality of my code (views, urls, models, forms):

**views.py:**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from taggit.models import Tag
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm, SearchForm
from .models import Post, Comment

# Create your views here.
class PostListView(ListView):
    queryset = Post.published.all()
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 3
    template_name = 'blog/post/list.html'

def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    object_list = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(object_list, 3) # Trzy posty na każdej stronie.
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # Jeżeli zmeinna page nie jest liczbą całkowitą,
        # wówczas pobierana jest pierwsza strona wyników.
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # Jeżeli zmienna page ma wartość większą niż numer ostatniej strony
        # wyników, wtedy pobierana jest ostatnia strona wyników.
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request,
            'blog/post/list.html',
            {'page': page,
            'posts': posts,
            'tag': tag})

def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,
            status='published',
            publish__year=year,
            publish__month=month,
            publish__day=day)

    # Lista aktywnych komentarzy dla danego posta.
    comments = post.comments.filter(active=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Komentarz został opublikowany.
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            # Utworzenie obiektu Comment, ale jeszcze nie zapisujemy go w bazie danych.
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Przypisanie komentarza do bieżącego posta.
            new_comment.post = post
            # Zapisanie komentarza w bazie danych.
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    # Lista podobnych postów.
    post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
    similar_posts = Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids)\
            .exclude(id=post.id)
    similar_posts = similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags'))\
            .order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]

    return render(request,
            'blog/post/detail.html',
            {'post': post,
                'comments': comments,
                'comment_form': comment_form,
                'similar_posts': similar_posts})

def post_share(request, post_id):
    # Pobranie posta na podstawie jego identyfikatora.
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, status='published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Formularz został wysłany.
        form = EmailPostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Weryfikacja pól formularza zakończyła się powodzeniem...
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(
                    post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) zachęca do przeczytania "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Przeczytaj post "{}" na stronie {}\n\n Komentarz dodany przez {}: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myblog.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post/share.html', {'post': post,
        'form': form,
        'sent': sent})

def post_search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    if 'query' in request.GET:
        form = SearchForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post)\
                    .filter(content=cd['query']).load_all()
            # Obliczenie całkowitej liczby wyników.
            total_results = results.count()
            return render(request,
                    'blog/post/search.html',
                    {'form': form,
                        'cd': cd,
                        'results': results,
                        'total_results': total_results})
    else:
        return render(request,
                'blog/post/search.html',
                {'form': form})
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment

class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    comments = forms.CharField(required=False,
            widget=forms.Textarea)

class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    query = forms.CharField()
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed

urlpatterns = [
        # Widoki posta.
        url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
        #url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
        url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/'\
                r'(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
                views.post_detail,
                name='post_detail'),
        url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share,
            name='post_share'),
        url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list,
            name='post_list_by_tag'),
        url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostsFeed(), name='post_feed'),
        url(r'^search/$', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
        ]
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

# Create your models here.
class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PublishedManager,
                self).get_queryset()\
                        .filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
            ('draft', 'Roboczy'),
            ('published', 'Opublikowany'),
            )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
            unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,
            related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
            choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
            default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()  # Menedżer domyślny
    published = PublishedManager()  # Menedżer niestandardowy
    tags = TaggableManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                args=[self.publish.year,
                    self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                    self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                    self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Komentarz dodany przez {} dla posta {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```